# PowerApps Web Part Width Cannot be Aligned with Other Webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powerapp

I added a vertical section to the page，then I add a PowerApps widget to the left horizontal column (One column). The ratio of my PowerApp is 16:9. When I add it to the page, even if I use the resize button to maximize the app, the width of the app still cannot be aligned with ‘call to action’, ‘News’ and other WebParts.（ Powerapps is always narrower than other webparts）

[image: The width of the added app cannot be aligned with other parts of the page]

Comment: Just a random thought: what if you try the `Embed` webpart instead? It might have smaller margins.

Comment: It does have smaller margins, but when the user adjusts the page zoom, the embedded part does not automatically adjust the display range according to the page zoom, so that the APP display is not complete